# Changing one model automatically Changes another in keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, google-colaboratory

(this is my first question ever!)
I am working in google colab. I fine tuned a Resnet50 model in keras and saved the weights.
Now, later during testing, I loaded the model weights like this:

```
res50 = keras.applications.ResNet50(weights= None, include_top=False, input_shape=(image_size, image_size, 3))

# Create the model
model = Sequential()

model.add(res50)

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))#0.75
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))#softmax #to Sigmoid

model.summary()

new_model = model    
new_model.load_weights('/content/drive/My Drive/model_weights.hdf5')

model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4),#1e-6
    loss="binary_crossentropy",
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)
```

Notice in last block, I compiled 'model', not 'new_model'. Yet I see that 'new_model' also becomes compiled. Further, I noticed that the weights of "model" are also updated, not just 'new_model'. Basically making any change to either changes the other. Why is this happening? Is this the right way to load the weights?
I have very basic understanding of programming. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are assigning to `new_model` a pointer to `model`, so basically `new_model` and `model` are referencing to the same variable.

You could solve this by creating an auxiliary function that generates a new model with the required structure:

```
def make_model(base_model):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(base_model)
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))#0.75
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))#softmax #to Sigmoid
    return model
```

Finally:

```
res50 = keras.applications.ResNet50(weights= None, include_top=False, input_shape=(image_size, image_size, 3))

# Create the model
new_model = make_model(base_model=res50)

new_model.summary()
  
new_model.load_weights('/content/drive/My Drive/model_weights.hdf5')

new_model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4),#1e-6
    loss="binary_crossentropy",
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)
```

In this way, if you need to create additional models in the future with the loaded weights of another model, you'll just need to do:

```
new_future_model = make_model(new_base_model)
```

Comment: Thank you. 
Can I ask, why is this a pointer? if we simply wrote :
'''
x =2, y=x, y=y+1.
'''
x would still remain 2, right?

Comment: This answer might help you out on this matter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/11050000

Comment: Basically, your keras model is a mutable object and so its assignment produces a reference to the original object (model, in your case)